# Is it possible to trigger events for google spreadsheet API V4 on save of new data on googlesheet?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, sendasynchronousrequest

I am trying to fetch data from a google sheet using Google sheet API V4. Is it possible anyhow to know if someone has saved a data or made changes on the sheet? Based on that I want to make call to the api to get the data?
More like I am trying to keep my application synced with the google sheet. As soon as someone update the data, my application gets updated too.
I am using Nodejs.
How  do I do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible using Google Sheets API. You may want to check this [pending feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759149). Try using Drive API - [Detect Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes) or [Apps Script - Simple Trigger OnChange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) for workaround. Hope this helps.

Comment: You could create a schedule to download the sheet every minute and compare it with the previous to check for changes.